# Is there an application to watch changes in auto starting apps and services?

Tags: bash, systemd, services, desktop, autostart

I'm thinking of developing an application to watch changes for auto starting applications and service that would notify when:

- A service state change (enabled/disabled/added/removed)
- An application is added/removed to boot
- Eventually revert the change

Auto start location to be watched:

- Systemd services
- Systemd timers
- Cron...
- `~/.kde/Autostart`
- `/etc/init.d/`
- `/etc/xdg/autostart/`
- `~/.xinitrc`
- etc.

Note that I am looking for a gui application eventually something that reside on the system tray or may be a script that pop-up a message/window.

1. There are some tools and command like `incron`, `diff <(cat old) <(cat new)`, `notify-send`, `zenity` and `gxmessage` to make it easy to write a bash script that could take care of all that but **is there an application that already do that?**
2. **Is there a similar tool** that I can start from to avoid writing everything from scratch or a tool/application that have a different purpose but could be transformed into the needed function? (any programming language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Startup-Watcher](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Apps/Startup-Watcher)

Ended up writing it from scratch...

- Watch for changes on 32 locations
- Notify when change occur
- Save change to /home/../.startup-watcher/changes
- Start hidden on the tray
- Root not required
- Watch root and user
- And much more.

**Captures**

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Apps/Startup-Watcher